# How to implement the segment function in cvxpy?

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

The objective function in my problem is construct as follows:

```
cp.Minimize(k*(w1*abs(x0-L10)+w2*abs(x1-L20))+β*Dindf[0]*(w1*alpha_beta(x0)+w2*alpha_beta(x1)+w1***alpha_beta**(x2)+w2*alpha_beta(x3)) +\
                k*(w1*abs(x2-x0) + w2*abs(x3-x1)+w1*abs(x4-x2) + w2*abs(x5-x3)))
```

The problem is I need the alpha_beta(x) function(wrt to the decision variables (x), shown as follows) to be a segment form, how can I code this function so that I can solve the problem?

```
def alpha_beta(x):
    a = 0.0019727939
    b = 0.0078887
    Lmin, Lnom, Lmax = 0.8035, 2.3811, 3.084
    return np.piecewise(x, [np.logical_and(Lmin <= x, x < Lnom),
                            np.logical_and(Lnom <= x, x <= Lmax)],
                        [lambda x: a * ((x - Lnom)**2) + 0.006226,
                         lambda x: b * ((x - Lnom)**2) + 0.006226, 0])
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe you will find a solution at https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/practical.html?highlight=piecewise#convex-univariate-piecewise-defined-functions

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I will check through this file.